# GLSL Bump Mapping Point Light

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, bump-mapping

**Recognize any logic errors?** Any suggestions to improve this code or to enhance the results?

Image: [Before & After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TomNd.jpg)

Video: [Short video demonstrating current bump mapping results!](https://youtu.be/auyjJl0nV5A)

The normal and tangent vectors being sent to the vertex shader are correct.

**Method in fragment shader:**

```
vec3 processPointLight(in vec3 norm, in vec3 pos, in int lightIndex)
{
    float distance = length(lights[lightIndex].Position.xyz - pos.xyz);

    //Light Attenuation Computation
    float attenuation = 1.0f / (
        (lights[lightIndex].AttenuationConst +
            lights[lightIndex].AttenuationLinear * distance +
            lights[lightIndex].AttenuationQuad * distance * distance));

    vec3 textureDifResult;
    vec3 textureSpecResult;
    if (Toggle_Textures)
    {
        vec3 textureNrmResult;
        textureDifResult =  textureLod(Texture0, ((fs_in.textureCoord.xy * (vec2(1024) / vec2(7168))) + (vec2(1024) * (fs_in.textureUnits.x + 0)) / vec2(7168)), 0).rgb;
        textureNrmResult =  textureLod(Texture0, ((fs_in.textureCoord.xy * (vec2(1024) / vec2(7168))) + (vec2(1024) * (fs_in.textureUnits.x + 1)) / vec2(7168)), 0).rgb;
        textureSpecResult = textureLod(Texture0, ((fs_in.textureCoord.xy * (vec2(1024) / vec2(7168))) + (vec2(1024) * (fs_in.textureUnits.x + 2)) / vec2(7168)), 0).rgb;
        // Transform normal vector to range [-1,1]
        norm = (textureNrmResult * 2.0f - vec3(1.0f));
    }
    else
    {
        textureDifResult = ModelColor.rgb;
        textureSpecResult = ModelColor.rgb;
    }
    //viewPoint, normal, tangent and bitangent are in view space so we need to transform the light's position to view space too.. Special thanks to pleup!
    vec3 L =normalize( mat3(fs_in.mv_Matrix) * lights[lightIndex].Position.xyz ) - fs_in.viewPoint;
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(dot(L, fs_in.tangent.xyz), dot(L, fs_in.bitangent.xyz), dot(L, norm)));
    vec3 reflection = reflect(-L, norm);
    // Light Diffuse Computation
    vec3 diffuse = ( max(0.0f, dot( norm ,lightDir )) * lights[lightIndex].Diffuse * textureDifResult);
    // Light Ambience Computation
    vec3 ambient = lights[lightIndex].Ambient;
    // Light Specular Computation
    vec3 specular = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //if (dot(lightDir , norm ) > 0.0f)
        specular = pow(max(0.0f, dot(reflect(-lightDir, norm), fs_in.eyeDir.xyz )), 20.0)  * textureSpecResult * lights[lightIndex].Specular * lights[lightIndex].SpecularPower;
    return  min((ambient)+attenuation * (diffuse + specular), vec3(1.0));
}
```

**Complete Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 420 core

layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_TexCoord;
layout(location=2) in vec4 in_Normal;
layout(location=3) in vec4 in_Tangent;
layout(location=4) in uvec4 in_TextureUnits;
// per frame
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 EyePosition;
// per item
uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelMatrixOrientation;


out VS_OUT
{
vec4 eyePosition;
vec4 worldPosition;
vec4 normal;
vec4 tangent;
vec4 bitangent;
vec4 eyeDir;
vec3 textureCoord;
flat uvec4 textureUnits;
vec3 viewPoint;
mat4 mv_Matrix;
} vs_out;

void main()
{

    gl_Position = ModelMatrix * in_Position;

    vs_out.worldPosition = ModelMatrix * in_Position;
    vs_out.eyePosition = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * in_Position;

    vs_out.textureCoord = vec3(in_TexCoord.x, in_TexCoord.y, in_TexCoord.z);
    vs_out.textureUnits = in_TextureUnits;

    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * gl_Position;



    vs_out.mv_Matrix = ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
        //vertex Position in view space..
    vec4 P =  vs_out.mv_Matrix  * in_Position;
    vs_out.viewPoint= P.xyz;
    vs_out.normal = normalize(vec4(mat3( vs_out.mv_Matrix) * in_Normal.xyz, 1.0f));
    // Calculate normal (N) and tangent (T) vectors in view space from incoming object space vectors.
    vs_out.tangent = normalize(vec4(mat3( vs_out.mv_Matrix ) * in_Tangent.xyz, 1.0f)  );

    // Calculate the bitangent vector (B) from the normal and tangent vectors
    vs_out.bitangent = vec4( cross(vs_out.normal.xyz, vs_out.tangent.xyz), 1.0f);

    // The view vector is the vector from the point of interest to the viewer, which in view space is simply the negative of the position.
    // Calculate that and multiply it by the TBN matrix.
    vec3 V = -P.xyz;
    vs_out.eyeDir = normalize(vec4(dot(V, vs_out.tangent.xyz), dot(V, vs_out.bitangent.xyz), dot(V, vs_out.normal.xyz),1.0f));

    return;
}
```

**Light properties:**

```
  <LightComponent type="PointLight" isEnabled="1" specularPower="1.0f" offsetX="0.0f" offsetY="40.0f" offsetZ="0.0f" ambientR="0.0f" ambientG="0.0f" ambientB="0.0f" diffuseR="0.3f" diffuseG="0.3f" diffuseB="0.3f" specularR="0.3f" specularG="0.3f" specularB="0.3f" attenConst="0.3f" attenLinear="0.000091427f" attenQuad="0.0000065429f" />
```

**Texture Manager function that loads the textures:**

```
void cTextureManager::loadTextureMipmap(rapidxml::xml_node<>* textureNode){
        std::string pathDif = textureNode->first_attribute("pathDif")->value();
        std::string pathNrm = textureNode->first_attribute("pathNrm")->value();
        std::string pathSpec = textureNode->first_attribute("pathSpec")->value();
        FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT imgFormat = FreeImage_GetFileType(pathDif.c_str(), 0);//Get current format (assume all textures are the same format)

        FIBITMAP* imagenDif = FreeImage_Load(imgFormat, pathDif.c_str());
        imagenDif = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(imagenDif);

        FIBITMAP* imagenNrm = FreeImage_Load(imgFormat, pathNrm.c_str());
        imagenNrm = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(imagenNrm);

        FIBITMAP* imagenSpec = FreeImage_Load(imgFormat, pathSpec.c_str());
        imagenSpec = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(imagenSpec);

        int width = FreeImage_GetWidth(imagenDif); // Assume images are the same size..
        int height = FreeImage_GetHeight(imagenDif);

        GLubyte* textureDif = new GLubyte[4 * width*height];
        GLubyte* textureNrm = new GLubyte[4 * width*height];
        GLubyte* textureSpec = new GLubyte[4 * width*height];

        char* pixelsDif = (char*)FreeImage_GetBits(imagenDif);
        char* pixelsNrm = (char*)FreeImage_GetBits(imagenNrm);
        char* pixelsSpec = (char*)FreeImage_GetBits(imagenSpec);
        //FreeImage loads in BGR format, so you need to swap some bytes(Or use GL_BGR).

        for (int j = 0; j<width*height; j++) {
            textureDif[j * 4 + 0] = pixelsDif[j * 4 + 2];
            textureDif[j * 4 + 1] = pixelsDif[j * 4 + 1];
            textureDif[j * 4 + 2] = pixelsDif[j * 4 + 0];
            textureDif[j * 4 + 3] = pixelsDif[j * 4 + 3];

            textureNrm[j * 4 + 0] = pixelsNrm[j * 4 + 2];
            textureNrm[j * 4 + 1] = pixelsNrm[j * 4 + 1];
            textureNrm[j * 4 + 2] = pixelsNrm[j * 4 + 0];
            textureNrm[j * 4 + 3] = pixelsNrm[j * 4 + 3];

            textureSpec[j * 4 + 0] = pixelsSpec[j * 4 + 2];
            textureSpec[j * 4 + 1] = pixelsSpec[j * 4 + 1];
            textureSpec[j * 4 + 2] = pixelsSpec[j * 4 + 0];
            textureSpec[j * 4 + 3] = pixelsSpec[j * 4 + 3];
        }
        int tempMipmapLevel = gCurrentMipmapLevel;
        std::string name = textureNode->first_attribute("name")->value();
        gMap_TextureNameToMipmapLevel[name] = tempMipmapLevel;
        gCurrentMipmapLevel+= 3;
        // Assume the texture is already bound to the GL_TEXTURE_2D target
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  // 2D texture
            0,                          // Level 0
            (1024 * tempMipmapLevel), (1024 * tempMipmapLevel),                           // Offset 0, 0
            1024, 1024,                 // 1024 x 1024 texels
            GL_RGBA,                    // Four channel data
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,           // Floating point data
            (GLvoid*)textureDif);       // Pointer to data
        delete [] textureDif;

        // Assume the texture is already bound to the GL_TEXTURE_2D target
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  // 2D texture
            0,             
            1024 * (tempMipmapLevel+1), 1024 * (tempMipmapLevel+1),           
            1024, 1024,       
            GL_RGBA,        
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,       
            (GLvoid*)textureNrm);         
        delete[] textureNrm;

        // Assume the texture is already bound to the GL_TEXTURE_2D target
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  // 2D texture
            0,             
            1024 * (tempMipmapLevel +2), 1024 * (tempMipmapLevel+2),           
            1024, 1024,       
            GL_RGBA,        
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,      
            (GLvoid*)textureSpec);          
        delete[] textureSpec;


        //  int MaxTextureImageUnits;
        //  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &MaxTextureImageUnits);
    }
```

**Thanks in advance for any advice!**

Comment: viewPoint, normal, tangent and bitangent are in view space in your fragment shader ( mv_Matrix * xxx ). So you need to transform lights positions to view space too.

Comment: Thank you @pleup! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Logical error: Your animal is made of bricks and can fly. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/